# How to call request every x seconds in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

Hi i'm triying to call a request biding to my table and refresh every x seconds

```
        getInfo : function() {
        variables ...
        oDataModel.read("/ReservaSet?$filter=Asesor eq '" + this.varGlob.asesor + "'", {
            success: function(oData, response) {
            var oResults = oData.results;
            oModel.setData(oData.results);
            tablaCitas.setModel(oModel);
             },
            Error: function(oError){
            }
        });
        this.closeDialog();
```

it is possible? i need to call it every 5 minutes and refresh my table

i read that i could use setInterval or setTimeout but how this is call it again and again if my function it's fired by a button ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the cells of a table in an interval time using OData model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379449/change-the-cells-of-a-table-in-an-interval-time-using-odata-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using    [sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger)
with an example [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/IntervalTrigger.html)

In a method you could add a listener function. You could start the triggering by setting the interval to the msecs (5mins: `setInterval(300000)`) when you press your button (if I understand this correctly to be your requirement) or during the `onInit` controller lifecycle event.

```
self = this;    
self.heartbeatTrigger = new sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger(0);   
self.heartbeatTrigger.addListener(function(){
    self.beat();
});
```

Your beat function could do the "Refresh" work.

```
beat : function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log('beat..');
    self.getInfo();
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do we remove the listener after a trigger?

Comment: @Vishnukk removeListener - the documentation link above refers